# Software for management of portfolio application

Tags: information-management

I’m looking for a software for portfolio management. I don't know what terms to search for this.

Here is my IT scenario:

- more than 100 applications
- several types of application servers, for example: JBOSS EAP 4,5,6 e Oracle IAS
- several types of test environments
- different applications types: internal and external

So I’m looking for a solution to organize this, registering:

```
App name.
App environment: development, test, production.
App application server name and version.
IP and DNS name.
Alias for app: myapp.example.com/app
Memory config.
Database type and version.
```

Comment: Not sure if this is of much help, but large corporations manage items like this through applications that provide Enterprise Asset Management or Enterprise Configuration Management functionality. Note esp. "Enterprise Asset Management" rather than just "Asset Management" (the latter term is often used in investing-related contexts).

Comment: Also there is a slight difference between Asset Management and Configuration management but this difference is not consistent. Configuration Management is often concerned about what hardware and software (services) do we have; the former is (more often) concerned about issues like the life-cycle of the assets. Still there is overlap between these two. Software that is used for these purposes typically allows storing the sort of information that you list in your question.

Comment: Also "Configuration Management" is also used by tools like CVS which serves a different purpose. Perhaps some searching for ITAM software may be the best bet.

Comment: Would a simple spreadsheet or database program work?

Comment: Here are some helpful questions to answer within *your* question: What operating system?  Gratis solutions? Paid solutions?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand … do you need a Web application (self-hosted or hosted), or a (single-user) desktop tool (if yes, which OS)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Application Portfolio Management](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-application-portfolio-manageme) template on Simitless. You can take it as an inspiration or use it straight away and modify it as you go along or as your needs evolve.

- The beauty of the system is that you are not limited to just a certain set of predefined parameters or columns that would structure your information management system.
- Instead, you yourself can determine what information you want to track/collect by selecting and then adding/removing/changing the names of the columns (like app name, app environment, etc.).
- Since it is a web app, it runs on any device with a browser, be it pc, tablet, phone, etc. and is always accessible.
- And, you can import/export your data at any time.

Here is a little screenshot what it looks like with some "dummy data" I input into the template:

1. Main view:
   [image]
2. One record view:
   [image]

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://semantic-mediawiki.org 
Especially, when you also want to manage how these systems relate to each other, like `depends on`, `supports`, etc., SMW is very handy. 
I once built a quite sophisticated system like this on SMW for a large german company. 
However, you would need to design the data model, entry forms and queries by yourself (or hire someone to do it). 
It's not out of the box. But the software itself is free.